# How can I insert a new Event for non primary Calendar using gdata.js?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am using gdata.js for inserting new Event.

I am able to insert only user's primary calendar.

The primary Calendar Feed uri is http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full

Which feed uri can I use for insert a new event other than primary calendar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The URI is in the form:

`http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/<CALENDAR_ID>/private/full`

You are currently using the ID 'default' which gives the users primary calendar.
What you need is the ID found on the details page of that calendar (near the bottom)
It is in the form:

`**************************@group.calendar.google.com`

so the full URI will be:

`http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/**************************@group.calendar.google.com/private/full`